# Blackberry: invoke constructor for verticalfieldmanager

Tags: blackberry

I want to run the constructor of a vertical field manager when used in a mainscreen:

```
vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(){

        protected void VerticalFieldManager(){
            System.out.println("Fresh");
        }

        protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight){              
            super.sublayout(maxWidth, 420);
            setExtent(maxWidth,420);
        }
    };
```

Of course, VerticalFieldManager does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot have a constructor in an anonymous class, that's just one of the rules of Java.

If you need to override the `VerticalFieldManager` constructor you will need to create your own class which extends `VerticalFieldManager`.